# How to login with mysql.exe, without command line

Tags: mysql

If it's possible, what command can be used to login to Mysql, **without using cmd.exe,** and by just running mysql.exe without any parameters? I don't need this, but I really don't like using the command line to login.

Comment: What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1. I am also using Mysql version 5.6.12.

Comment: Surely if you just execute it, it will prompt?

Comment: No, all it does is say, "Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with..." No prompt.